# DOS batch file to run 4 blocks of 3 parallel programs

Tags: batch-file

The program is a FORTAN number-crunching code :: "C:\fct1d_intel_2\debug\fct1d_intel_2.exe"
This is called using the batch file "RUN.bat":

```
C:\fct1d_intel_2\debug\fct1d_intel_2.exe
exit
```

The following batch file "run_generator_3procs_1to3.bat" kicks-off the 3 parallel programs in separate directories:

```
CD C:\FCT_Polystyrene_Model_Calibration\Proc_01
start /min run.bat
CD C:\FCT_Polystyrene_Model_Calibration\Proc_02
start /min run.bat
CD C:\FCT_Polystyrene_Model_Calibration\Proc_03
start /min run.bat
```

The following batch file "run_12_cases_4X3.bat" calls 4 sequential versions of of the preceding batchfile:

```
call run_generator_3procs_7to9.bat
call run_generator_3procs_10to12.bat
call run_generator_3procs_1to3.bat
call run_generator_3procs_4to6.bat
```

Now the first call "run_generator_3procs_7to9.bat" runs the 3 parallel programs fine but does not move on to the next 3 batch files.

Could anyone please advise me on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure `run_generator_3procs_7to9.bat` has precisely the same structure of the `run_generator_3procs_1to3.bat` you posted? I did a quick run with an similar setup and couldn't reproduce your problem. When I added an `EXIT` at the end of `run_generator_3procs_7to9.bat`, I got the behaviour you described.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are not trying to access files at the same time with different batch files. It might be executing, but just closing as they fail to run.